# Not receiving incoming messages on my mobile

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S2 mobile.
Since last week I have not been receiving any kind of incoming messages on my mobile.

1. I tried message centre no. deleted and re-enter, and powering off my mobile and restarting also.
2. My network setting also perfectly cross-checked, but still the problem was not resolved.
3. I called many times to customer care, but they are not properly responding at all.

Comment: Are you referring to SMS and MMS?  Do calls and mobile data work?

Answer (score 1):

If its not a network related issue then the problem could be from device itself. As Samsung Galaxy S2 has a built-in spam functionality in messaging.

So inorder to verify the same, just try sending sms with any another device on your S2 and just see if the other device gets a delivery confirmation report or not, if it does, and you still don't receive that sms. Then in this case you've unknowingly/accidentally switched on the spam function your Galaxy S2.

Follow the instruction below to unblock your incoming SMS

**Using the Settings menu**

- From any Home screen, tap **Messaging**.
- Tap the **Menu** key.
- Tap **Settings**.
- If necessary, tap Spam settings to select the check box
- Tap **Unregister number** as spam (if any)
- Touch and hold on the desired number and then tap **Delete**
- Tap **OK**

Hope this would resolve your problem :)